# double clicking .EXE different than using "start" in .bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe, steam

I made a .bat file to run CS:GO, using the command:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo.exe"
```

But when I run it, the game is started in "-insecure" mode, where I'm not allowed to join any servers.

When I hit the start button on Steam, it runs normally. 
Why is starting it from the batch file different than double clicking? (The same story for some other .exe's too)

Comment: I think you should check with Steam support. They may be doing some special checks on startup

Comment: Different parameters perhaps?

Comment: Check the shortcut properties.  They have probably defined a start directory and may also include some parameters that you are missing in your batch invocation.  They could also be loading it with a parent process to protect it from debuggers or provide some special keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
My batch file was starting csgo.exe, when steam was starting csgo using

```
steam://rungameid/730
```

My mistake:

Instead of starting programs using the link from the "create shortcut", I linked it directly to the .exe. I also fixed it with the other program, which I changed to launch "blahblah.ink" or something like that.

@jwdonahue, thanks for telling me to check the shortcut properties, that is where I found out shortcut stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're running csgo.exe individually, use this:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -login USERNAME PASSWORD -applaunch 730
```

If you want to run it with specific launch options, then use:

```
start /low "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -login USERNAME PASSWORD -applaunch 730 -nohltv -nosound -novid -window -w 640 -h 480 +exec yourcfg.cfg
```